# Set with complex numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, complex-numbers

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ c \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}$. Determine the set $$M := \{z \in \mathbb{C} | Re (\overline c z) + \alpha = 0 \}$$ and sketch it for $\alpha = 2, c=1+3i$ and $\alpha = 3, c= -1$.

My idea: Let $\overline c = a \pm bi, z = e+di$

$M := \{z \in \mathbb{C} | ae \pm bd + \alpha = 0 \}$

How to go on?

Comment: Why do you have the $\pm$ there? It only serves to confuse. Write $c=a+ib$ and $z=x+iy$, then compute the simple formula that $x,y$ satisfy (in terms of $a,b,\alpha$).

Comment: Because i have to make a case differentiation for $\overline c = a \pm bi$

Comment: You shouldn't reuse $c$ by setting $z=c+di$ for fear of confusion.  You can just say $\overline c=a+bi$

Answer (score 1):

In the first example (where $\alpha = 2, c= 1 +3 i$) you want to sketch all the $z = a + bi$ for which
$$\begin{align}
Re((1-3i)(a+bi)) + 2 &= 0 \quad \Rightarrow\\
Re(a - 3ai + bi + 3b + 2) &= 0 \quad \Rightarrow\\
a + 3b + 2 &= 0.
\end{align}
$$
That is you have
$$
b = -\frac{1}{3}a - \frac{2}{3}
$$
Here $b$ is the imaginary part of $z$ and $a$ is the real part of $z$. So what do you get in the complex plane?

Comment: Isn't this the second example? ( $\alpha$ must be $3$)?

Comment: @fear.xD: I meant the example with $\alpha = 2$.

Comment: But it's only that that $c= 1 +3 i$ in the secound example (note the ,)

Comment: @fear.xD: I am confused. So in the first example: $\alpha = 2, c = 1+ 3i$. In the second example $\alpha = 3, c = -1$. Is that right?

Comment: I've understood this exerice so, that in the first example only $\alpha$ is $2$ and c is unknown

Comment: @fear.xD: That might be true, but with the "and" I don't think that $c$ is unknown. If it was unknown, then the set would depend on $c$ and it would be hard to sketch the set...

Comment: Ok, this makes it much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

If $c=a+bi$ and $z=x+yi$, then $\bar{c}z=(ax+by)+(ax-by)i$, so you get
$$
ax+by+\alpha=0
$$
You know that $a$ and $b$ are not both zero, so this shouldn't be difficult to describe.

Comment: Why can we assume that $\overline c = a + bi$?

Comment: @fear.xD What do you mean? Since $c\in\mathbb{C}$, you can surely write it as $c=a+bi$, for unique $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $\bar{c}=a-bi$. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set $c=a+ib, z=x+iy$. Then $\operatorname{re} (\bar{c} z) = ax+by$.

Then $M=\{x+iy | ax+by+\alpha = 0 \}$. This will be a straight line.